# How to add un-indented bullets in RMarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown

Can you help me figure out how can I add some **un**-indented bullets in RMarkdown?

I tried it in Rmd file as below where **• abc** is from copy-paste, while ***abc** should be what I want, but it will automatically be indented: How can I get un-indented bullets (that means the **dot** position from **abc* should be in the same level of the header (**Test Un-indent Bullets**)?

Thanks!

```
# Test Un-indent Bullets

abc

* abc

• abc
```

[un-indented bullets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J9ln.png)

Comment: This will depend on the documentclass. Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: Just open a *.Rmd doc, and write down 3 rows like `1st row: # Test Un-indent Bullets; 2nd row: abc; 3rd row: * abc` and then knit it to PDF, you will see the *abc result will automatically indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
  \item one 
  \item two
  \item three
\end{itemize}
```

I found this one from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91124/itemize-removing-natural-indent

I can put this in the Rmd doc and the output PDF is what I want (bullets without indent).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The auto-indent happens because it's registering as a list, and I'm not sure how to disable that.

This might not be *exactly* what you're looking for, but you could just try copy pasting the bullet point symbol?

This one right here:  •

Comment: Thanks. The 3rd row is just as what you suggest. But I want to know if others have other ways to do it.